# How to combine multiple sourceSets

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse/ANT to Android Studio/Gradle.
Our current ant-build supports N customers (build-targets) and a customer is defined by a triplet skin/player/customer.
Every skin/player/customer may contain src, resources, assets, ...

What is the best way to model this in Gradle?

I currently create a productFlavor for every customer as follows

```
productFlavors {
     cust1{
         applicationId='com.xyz.cust1'
         customer="cust1"
         skin="skinX"
         player="playerA"
     }
     cust2{
         applicationId='com.xyz.cust2'
         customer="cust2"
         skin="skinY"
         player="playerB"
     } 
 }
```

but I have problems defining the corresponding sourceSets in a compact way.

I can write something like

```
sourceSets.cust1 {
    java.srcDir('pool/playerA/src')
    res.srcDir('pool/skinX/res')
    res.srcDir('pool/playerA/res')
    res.srcDir('pool/cust1/res')
    assets.srcDir('pool/playerA/assets')
    assets.srcDir('pool/skinX/assets')
    jniLibs.srcDir('pool/playerA/libs')
}
```

for every customer but this results in N almost identical sourceSets

I would prefer to have a single, parametrized, sourceSets like

```
sourceSets {
    java.srcDir('pool/${player}/src')
    res.srcDir('pool/${skin}/res')
    res.srcDir('pool/${player}/res')
    res.srcDir('pool/${customer}/res')
    assets.srcDir('pool/${player}/assets')
    assets.srcDir('pool/${skin}/assets')
    jniLibs.srcDir('pool/${player}/libs')
}
```

Is this possible?

One alternative could be to create a sourceSet for every player, skin and customer and create a sourceSet for the productFlavor by combining the main sourceSet with the ones of the player, skin and customer

Input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd investigate [flavor dimensions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) (formerly known as flavor groups, also known as multi-flavor variants).

Using those, you would set up three flavor dimensions, for skin, player, and customer. Each skin gets a `productFlavor` in the `skin` dimension, each player gets a `productFlavor` in the `player` dimension, and each customer gets a `productFlavor` in the `customer` dimension.

You would then have tasks like `assembleSkinxPlayeraCust1Debug`, which would build an app from `skinx`, `playera`, `cust1`, and `debug` sourcesets.