# How to iterate over all resource directories used

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse/ANT to Android Studio/Gradle.

Our application uses different layouts for xlarge/large (~tablet) and normal/small (~phone).
In our version control system, we only check-in the xlarge and normal variants and before releasing, we copy the xlarge to large and normal to small directories

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620746/how-to-combine-multiple-sourcesets), our releases are composed of multiple flavor dimensions.
And every flavor dimension contains some layout files

Hence I have to do this layout-copy for every used flavor dimension.

Can I somehow iterate over all used flavor dimensions that are used in a specific release?

Or is there a global resource (`sourceSets.res.getResources()`?) I can iterate on? If so, what is the best place in the gradle build to do this?

Comment: Do you really need copying xlarge and normal directories? System will scale down resources to proper size.

Comment: @MateuszJablonski: we copy layout files (not images): if we don't copy, we would have only layout-xlarge and layout-normal and then I guess, the application would crash on a 'large' or a 'small' device because it would not find a valid layout file

Comment: Ok I understand. I personally have gradle setup with 3 main res folders and additional two for two separate flavours, but non of my setups require copying. I think there is something in gradle system that will allow you to automatically copy files from one directory to another before build. Too bad I can't help you.